# Pandas not detecting the datatype of a Series properly

Tags: pandas, type-conversion, series

I'm running into something a bit frustrating with pandas Series. I have a DataFrame with several columns, with numeric and non-numeric data. For some reason, however, pandas thinks some of the *numeric* columns are non-numeric, and ignores them when I try to run aggregating functions like `.describe()`. This is a problem, since pandas raises errors when I try to run analyses on these columns.

I've copied some commands from the terminal as an example. When I slice the 'ND_Offset' column (the problematic column in question), pandas tags it with the dtype of `object`. Yet, when I call `.describe()`, pandas tags it with the dtype `float64` (which is what it should be). The 'Dwell' column, on the other hand, works exactly as it should, with pandas giving `float64` both times.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this behavior?

```
In [83]: subject.phrases['ND_Offset'][:3]
Out[83]: 
SubmitTime
2014-06-02 22:44:44    0.3607049
2014-06-02 22:44:44    0.2145484
2014-06-02 22:44:44    0.4031347
Name: ND_Offset, dtype: object

In [84]: subject.phrases['ND_Offset'].describe()
Out[84]: 
count     1255.000000
unique     432.000000
top          0.242308
freq        21.000000
dtype: float64

In [85]: subject.phrases['Dwell'][:3]
Out[85]: 
SubmitTime
2014-06-02 22:44:44    111
2014-06-02 22:44:44     81
2014-06-02 22:44:44    101
Name: Dwell, dtype: float64

In [86]: subject.phrases['Dwell'].describe()
Out[86]: 
count    1255.000000
mean       99.013546
std        30.109327
min        21.000000
25%        81.000000
50%        94.000000
75%       111.000000
max       291.000000
dtype: float64
```

And when I use the `.groupby` function to group the data by another attribute (when these Series are a part of a DataFrame), I get the `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` error when I try to call `.agg(np.mean)` on the group. When I try to call `.agg(np.sum)` *on the same data*, on the other hand, things work fine.

It's a bit bizarre -- can anyone explain what's going on?

Thank you!

Comment: We need to figure out why it's `dtype=object`.  What happens when you try `subject.phrases['ND_Offset'].astype(float)`?

Comment: It converts just fine if I cast it explicitly in that way; my confusion is why it didn't recognize it in the first place. Elsewhere in the library, I wrote a parser which takes .csv files and converts them to this DataFrame. I explicitly cast the 'ND_Offset' Series to a float there, but when I load up the DataFrame it thinks its an object again. That was the strangest thing of all, to be honest.

Comment: I suppose I could cast the Series to a float upstream in the program as needed, but that would make the code less DRY. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @kronosapiens doing ``.describe()`` returns the dtype of the DESCRIBE results (not the original column!)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the `ND_Offset` column (what I call `A` below) contains a non-numeric value such as an empty string. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.36, ''], 'B': [111, 81]})
print(df['A'].describe())
# count     2.00
# unique    2.00
# top       0.36
# freq      1.00
# dtype: float64

try:
    print(df.groupby(['B']).agg(np.mean))
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
    # No numeric types to aggregate

print(df.groupby(['B']).agg(np.sum))
#         A
# B        
# 81       
# 111  0.36
```

Aggregation using `np.sum` works because

```
In [103]: np.sum(pd.Series(['']))
Out[103]: ''
```

whereas `np.mean(pd.Series(['']))` raises

```
TypeError: Could not convert  to numeric
```

---

To debug the problem, you could try to find the non-numeric value(s) using:

```
for val in df['A']:
    if not isinstance(val, float):
        print('Error: val = {!r}'.format(val))
```

Comment: But the OP said that `subject.phrases['ND_Offset'].astype(float)` works.  (Of course, "transcript or it didn't happen", as the kids say.)

Comment: Well, perhaps the example could be shoehorned to fit that clue by changing the empty string to `'nan'`. But trying to guess the exact cause without a runnable example is probably a long shot, so the main point is just that there is something in that column which is non-numeric.